# Using WHERE to filter a CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to filter the result set on the variables that are listed in the CASE statements.

```
SELECT u.id,
max(t.request_at) AS "Date",
sum(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
sum(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
sum(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 3 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS THREE

FROM users u

JOIN t ON u.id = t.uid

WHERE u.signup_city_id = 18
AND u.creationtime BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01'

group by 1
```

I would really like to filter something along the lines of: WHERE ONE < 3

i.e. Where the column one is smaller than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT u.id, max(t.request_at) AS "Date",
       sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
       sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
       sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS THREE
FROM users u JOIN
     t
     ON u.id = t.uid
WHERE u.signup_city_id = 18 AND u.creationtime BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01'
group by 1
HAVING sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 3;
```

Or use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT u.id, max(t.request_at) AS "Date",
             sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
             sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
             sum(CASE WHEN t.view = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS THREE
      FROM users u JOIN
           t
           ON u.id = t.uid
      WHERE u.signup_city_id = 18 AND u.creationtime BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01'
      group by 1
     ) t
WHERE ONE < 3;
```

Comment: `Having one` won't work as `one` isn't actually a real column, you need the aggregate statement instead.

Comment: Looks like you've updated your answer accordingly, looks good, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
    SELECT u.id,
           max(t.request_at) AS "Date",
           sum(CASE
               WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
           sum(CASE
               WHEN t.view = 2 THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
           sum(CASE
               WHEN t.view = 3 THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END) AS THREE
    FROM users u
      JOIN t ON u.id = t.uid
    WHERE u.signup_city_id = 18
      AND u.creationtime BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01'
    group by 1
) t
WHERE ONE < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of the `SUM` of the `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT u.id,
    max(t.request_at) AS "Date",
SUM(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 3 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS THREE
FROM users u
JOIN t ON u.id = t.uid
WHERE u.signup_city_id = 18
AND u.creationtime BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(CASE
    WHEN t.view = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) < 3
```